# Is there a way of running a script *within Rstudio* via windows command line?

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, jobs

I'd like to set a scheduled task to run a script on startup which launches a set of APIs via rstudio's jobs. I've tried running this in powershell via the command "R path/to/job_script.R" but get the following error:

```
Error in check_available() :
  You must run this from the RStudio main session.
```

So it seems this must be run from within Rstudio. I'm wondering is there a way of telling rstudio to open AND set this script running? trying "rstudio path/to/script.R will just open the script within rstudio, but not actually run it.

I know I could set each api to launch via a separate R script, but this then makes monitoring a nightmare as I'll have to look through 10 different r windows instead of a single rstudio window.

Edit: Comments seem to be misunderstanding what I'm trying to achieve. I'm specifically trying to launch a suite of tools via multiple instances of **Rstudio's new jobs feature**. Running an r script from cmd is not sufficient to achieve this as I want a single place to be able to view logs etc on all of my tools.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do but are you looking for `help("source")`?

Comment: Look at `?Rscript` and `?BATCH`

Comment: maybe start small and run a dummy script via Rscript.exe first and from there go and identify which parts of your original script rely on RStudio - most of them can be substituted by cmd compatible code (like going from an rstudioapi function to a tcltk solution if you have GUI elements - just an example)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but running via separate r sessions wasn't sufficient for what I wanted. I've posted my preferred solution below.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out eventually. The trick is to place your jobs script in the .Rprofile of a .Rproj. Then use the rstudioapi package to set a hook on project startup. Here's a rough skeleton of what my .Rprofile looks like:

```
setHook("rstudio.sessionInit", function(newSession) {
  if (newSession) {
    apis = list(
      list(
        name = "api1",
        host = "<server_ip>",
        port = "1111",
        wd = "path/to/working_dir1"
      ),
      list(
        name = "api2",
        host = "<server_ip>",
        port = "1112",
        wd = "path/to/working_dir2"
      ),
    )
    
    message("Launching All APIs")
    
    for (api in apis) {
      #all my projects have a run_api.R file at their root:
      #might be cleaner to just plumb from here directly?
      job::job({
        source(file.path(root_dir, app[["dir"]], "run_api.R"))
      },
      opts = options(
        host = api$host,
        port = api$port,
        wd = api$wd
      )),
      title = app[["name"]])


    }
    
  }, action = "append")
```

This combines the rstudioapi package and job package functionality, and can be used to launch shiny apps, plumber apis etc.

Now I can set a scheduled task in windows to set all these apis running on startup through a single rstudio session, via a cmd line:

```
"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" "path\to\project\runAPIs.Rproj"
```

and in the end I'm left with a very nice high level display of all my apps/apis via the rstudio jobs tab:

[image]